# How can I clean up data from a Model, and include HTML as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, model

In my Rails app, I've got a model called `Video`, and each video has a `rating:integer`. The ratings are from `1` to `5`. However, when I display them to the user, I want to make them look nice. So for now, using text, I replace a rating of 3 with `***..`, for instance.

In my `video.rb` I've got:

```
def graphical_rating
    stars = ''
    no_stars = ''

    rating.times { stars += '*' }
    (5 - rating).times { no_stars += '.' }

    return stars + no_stars
end
```

Now, I want to add some HTML to it, so that it outputs `<span class="stars">***</span><span class="no-stars">..</span>` but it outputs as text rather than HTML.

What's the best way of handling this so that it's still as easy as it was before (I could just use `video.graphical_rating`) while being able to also include HTML?

Comment: You don't need to `return` on last line of method. Returns are implicit in Ruby. `stars + no_stars` would be returned without return statement.

Comment: Yeah I know, but it makes more sense to me to have the return.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it makes more sense to you. It's Ruby convention to not return. Always assume other developers will eventually work with your code. By working in Ruby, or any language, you're contributing to the community in some way, and you will only frustrate other developers if you use return statements everywhere. Read the [style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). Stick to the conventions of the language/framework you're working in and you'll save yourself a few headaches (especially when it comes to reading other people's code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method actually belongs in your `VideoHelper` file because it only only applies to your views, not the logic of the model.

This should work:

```
def graphical_rating(rating)
stars = ''
no_stars = ''

rating.times { stars += '*' }
(5 - rating).times { no_stars += '.' }

return raw("<span class='stars'>#{stars}</span><span class='no-stars'>#{no_stars}</span>")
end
```

Then, in the view you can call it with:

```
<%= graphical_rating(@video.rating) %>
```

Comment: Thanks I did that, works. Although I like the "simplicity" of `@video.graphical_rating` still.